# How to make calculation while receiving new data?

Tags: c#, real-time

I try to make a realtime classification desktop app using C#. Classification based on KNN algorithm. I got the data from sensor, I read it using timer_tick (i got 100 data every 1 second or read the data every 10 ms).

I want to start the classification by taking every 280 data i have one at a time. (means I run classification code every 0 - 279, 280 - 559, ...)

I do have alot of problem :

1. For now i dont implement any thread or task, so the UI freeze whenever i called the doKNNClassification() which also means while the doKNNClassification() running i am not receiving any new data
2. it takes alot of time to do KNN (estimation, **minimum** time I get to do KNN on 280 data is 4 minutes) meanwhile it just take 2.8 seconds to get new 280 data which means it is time to run the classification function again. (What happened if call the same function again while it is still running)

How to make the program to keep receiving new data while also do another task/function whenever i got enough data ?

*I hope i write this one clear enough and really appreciate any suggestion

This some code I write so far

```
    Sensor varSensorHelper = new Sensor(); // Custom class
    List<Sensor> listSensorMeasurement = new List<Sensor>();

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // 2520 = 9 x 280
            string text = ""; // Use this var for displaying the sensor measurement on the UI
            
            // if i have 2520, i will stop receiving data sensor
            if (arraySensor.Count < 2520)
            {
                
                if (arraySensor.Count % 280 != 0)
                {
                    // this part is to separate which data belong to which sensor 
                    // I use 3 sensor, identified by the sensor ID which is CC2, C42, C62
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, ConnectedMtData> data in _connectedMtwData)
                    {

                        if (data.Value._orientation != null)
                        {   
                            if (Regex.IsMatch(data.Key.ToString(), patternCC2))
                            {
                                varSensorHelper.Roll1 = data.Value._orientation.x();
                                varSensorHelper.Pitch1 = data.Value._orientation.y();
                                varSensorHelper.Yaw1 = data.Value._orientation.z();
                            }
                            else if (Regex.IsMatch(data.Key.ToString(), patternC42))
                            {

                                varSensorHelper.Roll2 = data.Value._orientation.x();
                                varSensorHelper.Pitch2 = data.Value._orientation.y();
                                varSensorHelper.Yaw2 = data.Value._orientation.z();

                            }
                            else if (Regex.IsMatch(data.Key.ToString(), patternC62))
                            {
                                //MASUKKAN DATA SENSOR KE ROW BARU
                                varSensorHelper.Roll3 = data.Value._orientation.x();
                                varSensorHelper.Pitch3 = data.Value._orientation.y();
                                varSensorHelper.Yaw3 = data.Value._orientation.z();
                            }
                            text += string.Format("{3:X8} {0,-5:f2}, {1,-5:f2}, {2,-5:f2} [°]\n",
                                                data.Value._orientation.x(),
                                                data.Value._orientation.y(),
                                                data.Value._orientation.z(), data.Key);

                            listSensorMeasurement.add(varSensorHelper);

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    doKNNClassification();


                }
            }
            else
            {
               //I have enough data, I need to stop this timer_tick function

            }
            
           
            
        }
```

Comment: _"How to make the program to keep receiving new data while also do another task/function whenever i got enough data ?"_ - A CPU-Bound Task will get you executing on the threadpool. Another possibility would be DataFlow, maybe. Both of wich will lead to your EventHandler being async `private async void timer2_Tick(...)`

Comment: `doKNNClassification();` this hint to being dependent on sideeffects and also causing sideeffects. You may want to avoid that.

Comment: You should be able to use System.Threading for that. Simply make `doKNNClassification()` return a Task and wrap its content in following code:

`return Task.Run(() =>{ *function content* });`

What it does is that it assigns a worker thread for the code inside and makes it run somewhere else than UI thread. However, be careful if you wanna do any front-end changes with that function, because worker thread can't work with UI

Comment: ^^ That's overcome easily, though, by using `IProgress<T>`

Comment: @Fildor So, you suggesting make the timer_tick to be asynchronous ? And for my case i dont need to `await` any of that ? Also sir, `timer_tick()` is automatically run every 10 ms, also what happened if `timer_tick()` is run again for a second time while the the first run isnt finished yet ?

Comment: @MartinPřívozník Thank you for the respond. I have question about that `Task.Run()`, what happened if call that `Task.RUn()` again and again without waiting it to finish ? (It can happened because i will call the `doKNNClassification()` approximately every 2.8 seconds) meanwhile the `doKNNClassification()` will run for at least 4 minutes

Comment: Well, making it async _alone_, won't help. I think you need a combination of off-loading and optimization. A 4 minute run to compute something on 280 datapoints seems ridiculously slow to me. So, you are either computing something _very_ complicated or you are doing it inefficiently. Or both.

Comment: The point of "pipelining" runs (strat the next before the current has finished) is strongly related to your computation method relying heavily on sideeffects. We do not see its implementation, so I can say not much about it, other than it probably should have input params and maybe it should return something.

Comment: @Fildor well, KNN algorithm need new data and datasets. I have 50k datasets, which means i have to loop through 280 x 50k. Maybe the reason I have 4 minutes is because inneficient code, but i strongly believe the reason is because the massive dataset. I have try to reduce the dataset and the I got 4 minute now, before I have like 180k data it took like 15 - 20 minute

Comment: @TriskKhan Every time you call it, a system assigns a new thread for it that is actually free. If you manage to call it every 2.8 seconds and wait for 4 minutes it might take all your threads really fast... After every thread is taken, it is gonna wait for some of it to be freed in the background.  You can imagine it like a queue. I can tell you it wont be that efficient because the worker thread computations are gonna be so far behind the real code. However it wont freeze your UI thread

Comment: In your situation I would consider having a separate background service for the long calculations. But as @Fildor says, you should reconsider how often you make the calculations, maybe do it every 1-2 minutes..? Do you really need to analyze all of the data?